# Как в сервлете не обрабатывать первый запрос

Tags: java, servlet

Есть сервлет, он обрабатывает данные формы, все бы хорошо, но он обрабатывает первый запрос от клиента и `input` которые еще пустые и возвращают `null`.

Можно сделать просто проверку на `null`, но думаю что есть более правильный способ для обработки первого и повторного запроса с заполненными полями.

```
public class Join extends HttpServlet {
    PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String template = "join.xsl";

        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        Document pageXml = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element root = pageXml.addElement("page");
        try {
            XslXmlTransformer.getInstance(resp, session, "template").writeHtml(pageXml, template);
        } catch (Exception er){ System.err.println(er); }
        String name = req.getParameter("name") + "";
        System.out.println(name);
        out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(name);
        out.print(req.getParameter("number"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
```

а вот xsl

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal jsRequiredContainer" action="/join" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5"><b>Ваше имя</b></label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5"><b>Контактный телефон</b></label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control jsMask" name="number" data-mask="+7 999 999-99-99" placeholder="+7 ___ ___-__-__"  />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5"><b>Электронная почта</b></label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5"><b>Название компании</b></label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameComp" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-controls clearfix">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-5"> </label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-lg" ><b>Отправить</b></button>
            <p class="jsRequiredTip">Пожалуйста, заполните все поля</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать проверить наличие сессии. Идея в том, что при первом обращении к сервлету не будет сессии:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null) { //нет сессии
    session = request.getSession();
} else { //сессия есть
}
```

ну и организовать ветвление по наличию сессии.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так более грамотнее чем проверять значения в полях